# How to touch kernel thread stack's 8K bytes limitation?

Tags: linux, kernel

As I know, Linux kernel has a limitation of its kernel thread stack's size, that is 4K or 8K for most architectures. I want to know how to touch it?
I use kthread_run() to create a kernel thread theKernelThread() and allocate stack whose size is bigger than 8K and run it, but it runs well. Why? How to make a code which touches the limitation and could cause kernel panic?

```
static int theKernelThread(void *pUsrdata)
{
    int     test[82000];
    static int count;

    while(1)
    {    
        count++;
        test[count % 81999] = count % 0xff;
        printk("tomxue: test=0x%x, count=%d\n", test[count], count);
        ...
        msleep(2);
    }
}
```